# How to proxy nginx request to tomcat path?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I have a Domain Name example.com. When enter `example.com` I want to proxy the request to `127.0.0.1:8080/source`

My nginx configuration

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }
```

This works for 127.0.0.1:8080, but I can't get it to proxy to the /source subidrectory. When I change to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/source/;
```

It doesn't work correctly.

It redirect to  http://127.0.0.1:8080/source/ good, but the  js and css file path is `/source/js/ *.js`  and  `/source/css/ *.css`  , and other resource file is `/source/*`.
For example , when brower load the html ,  it will  try to find the `/source/js/ *.js`,
for the reason that  I redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/source/` , the finnally path is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/source/source/js/ *.js` , but the right path is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/source/js/ *.js`

I just want that  when i  enter the **example.com** , it will redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8080/source/ , or redirect to   `example.com/source`  is ok too.

Comment: The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) says the proxy_pass to the subdirectory should work fine. Please edit your question to give more detail. I suggest you use _curl_ to make a request, then include the matching entries Nginx access log, the Nginx error log, and the tomcat access/error logs. Don't just dump all the logs, make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: I have update detail

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. I assume English isn't your first language. If you could please try to make things similar, provide examples, and format it well. For example you could give a list of source URLs, then the URL you want it to proxy to, each on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of your question suggests that all you need to do is rewrite a single URI. This can be accomplished a number of ways, but an exact match `location` with a `rewrite...last` would look like this:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /source/ last;
}
location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
 listen      80;
 server_name hello.example.me;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

  location = / {
    rewrite ^ /HELLO/ last;
}
  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

Works like a charm. Feel free to add more paths.